Getting empty dataframes after webscraping from Wikipedia
I am trying to extract data from a wikipedia page and load it into a dataframe. After webscraping and running the data frame, python is returning an empty data frame which shouldn't be the case. Here's my code snippet :
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})
rows = table.find_all('tr')[1:]
countries = []
hdi_index = []
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    if len(cols) > 2:
        countries.append(cols[1].text.strip())
        hdi_index.append(cols[2].text.strip())
hdi_df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': countries, 'HDI': hdi_index})
print(hdi_df.head())



Are you sure the table you want is the first one? You might need to use soup.find_all:
tables = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})

Then identify the one you need.
That said, you could do much simpler and directly use pandas.read_html:
tables = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_Human_Development_Index')
hdi_df = tables[1][['Country or territory', 'HDI value']]

Output:
         Country or territory  HDI value
0                 Switzerland      0.967
1                      Norway      0.966
2                     Iceland      0.959
3                   Hong Kong      0.956
4                     Denmark      0.952
..                        ...        ...
188                     Niger      0.394
189                      Chad      0.394
190  Central African Republic      0.387
191               South Sudan      0.381
192                   Somalia      0.380

[193 rows x 2 columns]


getting error messages when I am calling find_all() or pandas.read_html() function.

@ArbabQaisar which errors…? Works fine for me. We can't troubleshoot without an explicit error traceback. Please edit your question with details.

I am receiving error messages when I'm trying to apply your suggestions.  For example if I use the find_all method on soup:
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Now I have managed to get the HDI scores but not the names of the countries
